# Intel Centrino Wireless N2230 Wifi Adapter is not being detected in Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, dell, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I have a Dell Inspiron 15R 5521 laptop and I recently dual-booted my system with Xubuntu 16.04. But the Intel Centrino Wireless N 2230 is not being detected and thus I am unable to use the internet. Please help me out here. Here are the logs:-

```
        $ sudo lshw -C network
    [sudo] password for max: 
      *-network               
           description: Ethernet interface
           product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
           vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
           logical name: enp1s0
           version: 05
           serial: b8:ca:3a:c3:de:de
           size: 10Mbit/s
           capacity: 100Mbit/s
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
           resources: irq:27 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0404000-c0404fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
      *-network
           description: Ethernet interface
           physical id: 2
           bus info: usb@3:4
           logical name: enp0s20u4c4i2
           serial: 62:f4:45:cb:75:69
           capabilities: ethernet physical
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth ip=172.20.10.2 link=yes multicast=yes

    $ nmcli device 
        DEVICE         TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION    
        enp0s20u4c4i2  ethernet  connected    Auto Ethernet 
        enp1s0         ethernet  unavailable  --            
        lo             loopback  unmanaged    --         

        $ ifconfig 
    enp0s20u4c4i2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 62:f4:45:cb:75:69  
              inet addr:172.20.10.2  Bcast:172.20.10.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
              inet6 addr: fe80::a6a5:51b0:8d0e:d29d/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:39104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:28879 errors:7 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:49517627 (49.5 MB)  TX bytes:2490547 (2.4 MB)

    enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ca:3a:c3:de:de  
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:1406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:1406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
              RX bytes:98562 (98.5 KB)  TX bytes:98562 (98.5 KB)

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)

$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
[sudo] password for max: 
rmmod: ERROR: missing module name.
```

Okay. Here you go.

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:58c2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone5/5C/5S/6
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: The wireless chip is not seen. This means it is disabled in BIOS, having a bad contact, or broken. Try to reset BIOS to defaults.

Comment: Reset the BIOS to defaults. Still nothing.